# Find the maximum value of the fraction

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers satisfying $\frac{ab+1}{a+b}<\frac{3}{2}$. The maximum possible value of $\frac{a^3b^3+1}{a^3+b^3}$ is $\frac{p}{q}$, where $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime positive integers. Find $p+q$.

Trial and error makes the job very easy, but it isn't rigorous.

I used factoring:

$$= \frac{(ab + 1)(a^2b^2 - ab + 1)}{(a+b)(a^2 - ab + b^2)} < \frac{3}{2} \cdot \bigg( \frac{a^2b^2 -ab + 1}{a^2 -ab + b^2} \bigg)$$

But that doesnt get you anywhere either.

**Hints only please!**

Comment: The first inequality you gave is pretty sharp, and this combined with the fact that $a$ and $b$ are integers really limits the possibilities.

Comment: See how far writing the expression on the last line on the right as $\dfrac{(ab+1)^2-3ab}{(a+b)^2-3ab}$ can get you. You should be able to relate the terms on the left to the limiting value of the first inequality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without loss of generality, we assume that $a\leq b$.  Since $a=2\left(\frac{ab}{2b}\right)\leq2\left(\frac{ab}{a+b}\right)< 2\left(\frac{ab+1}{a+b}\right)<3$, we have $a=1$ or $a=2$.  If $a=1$, then $b$ can be any natural number and $\frac{a^3b^3+1}{a^3+b^3}=1$.  If $a=2$, then $\frac{2b+1}{b+2}=\frac{ab+1}{a+b}<\frac{3}{2}$ gives $4b+2<3b+6$, or $b<4$.  The rest is only checking with $(a,b)\in\big\{(2,2),(2,3)\big\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Try manipulating the first inequality to define $a$ in terms of $b$ (or vice versa)

$$ \frac{ab+1}{a+b} < \frac{3}{2} \Rightarrow 2ab+2 < 3a+3b$$ 
$$ \Rightarrow 2ab - 3a < 3b-2 $$ 
$$ \Rightarrow a < \frac{3b-2}{2b-3}$$

Notice that if $a=1$, then the second fraction involving $a$ and $b$ would become
$$ \frac{(1)^3b^3+1}{(1)^3+b^3} = \frac{b^3+1}{b^3+1} = 1$$

Similarly, if $b=1$, this second fraction would become
$$ \frac{a^3(1)^3+1}{a^3+(1)^3} = \frac{a^3+1}{a^3+1} = 1$$

Let's exclude these possibilities for $a$ and $b$ because they don't offer much useful information for finding a maximum bound. Then since $a$ and $b$ are both positive integers, we can setup a new inequailty for $a > 2$ using the value of $a$ we defined in terms of $b$

$$ \frac{3b-2}{2b-3} > 2$$

Since we want $b > 1$, we can multiply both sides by $2b-3$ to simplify

\begin{align*}
\frac{3b-2}{2b-3}\cdot (2b-3) &> 2\cdot(2b-3)\\
3b-2 &> 4b-6\\
\Rightarrow b < 4
\end{align*}

Since you said "Hints only" I'll leave the rest up to you. Let me know if you'd like further help!